# Boost Python: Delete objects from C++

Tags: python, boost-python

Short explanation. I am writing a game engine. I am using OpenGL for rendering and Boost::Python for scripting. Everything works perfectly for now. I am implementing listener classes that process events. For example this class triggers events during rendering:

```
class FrameListener
    {
    public:
        struct FrameEvent
        {
            double TimeSinceLastEvent;
            double TimeSinceLastFrame;
        };

        virtual void FrameStart(FrameEvent& evt) = 0;
        virtual void FrameEnd(FrameEvent& evt) = 0;
        virtual void OnFrame(FrameEvent& evt) = 0;
    };
```

This is a base FrameListener class with 3 events that trigger during different render stages. And here is the wrapper class for python:

```
class FrameListener_PyWrapper : public FrameListener, public boost::python::wrapper<FrameListener>
    {
        public:
          FrameListener_PyWrapper() {}

        void FrameStart(FrameEvent& evt)
        {
            if (boost::python::override f = this->get_override("FrameStart"))
            {
                f(evt); // *note*
                return;
            }
        }

        void FrameEnd(FrameEvent& evt)
        {
            if (boost::python::override f = this->get_override("FrameEnd"))
            {
                f(evt); // *note*
                return;
            }
        }

        void OnFrame(FrameEvent& evt)
        {
            if (boost::python::override f = this->get_override("OnFrame"))
            {
                f(evt); // *note*
                return;
            }
        }
    };
```

This works perfectly. I can for example create this class in python, which will shutdown the game in 10 seconds:

```
class SimpleListener(FrameListener):
time = 0
def __init__(self):
    super(self.__class__, self).__init__()
def OnFrame(self, evt):
    self.time += evt.TimeSinceLastFrame
    if self.time > 10:
        CORE_ENGINE.Shutdown()
```

Then by calling CORE_ENGINE.AddListener(SimpleListener()) from python the listener is added to std::vector FrameListeners:

```
if (FrameListener* listen = boost::python::extract< FrameListener* >(listener))
    {
        FrameListeners.push_back(listen);
    }
```

All this works perfectly ass expected. But then I have function RemoveAllListeners which should remove all listeners. I have tried something like this:

```
    vector<FrameListener*>::iterator it;
for ( it = FrameListeners.begin(); it != FrameListeners.end(); ){
      delete * it;         
}
```

Which obviously crashes. I assume that the pointer to base FrameListener is destroyed but python SimpleListener objects remains as dangling pointer? How could I properly destroy those python inherited FrameListeners from C++ code?

cheers Puso!

Comment: Seems like you are iterating the listeners without ever calling the iterator next. Is this the actual code you are running?

Comment: Be cautious when extracting a handle to a C++ object embedded within a  Python object.  Ownership semantics need to be clear and explicit.  When one calls `listener = SimpleListener(); CORE_ENGINE.AddListener(listener)`, should Python be transferring ownership of `listener` to C++, and the caller is never expected to invoke a method on `listener`?  Also, is multithreading involved?

Comment: probably ownership of listener should be transferred to C++. This is a listener, which is added to a vector of listeners. Every frame the engine iterates through vector and triggers OnFrame methods. So listener methods are not intended to be called from python but internally from engine in C++. The listener itself works fine, it stops engine after 10 seconds but I need a method to remove a listener from vector and probably destroy it to prevent preformance issues. After end of game level you probably would want to destroy listeners that are used within the level.